# React callback to scroll after all children are rendered

Tags: reactjs, redux

I need to execute a piece of code after all grandchildren of a Component are rendered to scroll to one of the grandchildren. The structure looks like this:

```
`<GrandParent>
   <IntermediateParent>
     <IntermediateParent2>
       <GrandChild/>
       <GrandChild/>
       <GrandChild/>
       <GrandChild/>
     </IntermediateParent2>
   </IntermediateParent>
 </GrandParent>`
```

The render method of `GrandParent` looks like this:

```
render() {
  if (!this.props.listOfGrandchildren) { // still loading data from server
    return <div>LOADING...</div>
  }

  return <IntermediateParent grandchildren={this.props.listOfGrandchildren} />
}
```

It is clear that using `ComponentDidMount` will clearly not work because of the children being mounted at a later time, after the data is loaded from the server. In this case, CDM of `GrandParent` would be triggered before CDM of any `GrandChild`

I could pass down a method from top to each `GrandChild` that would be called at CDM. On GrandParent I would wait for all `GrandChild` to call that method by using a counter and once the counter would be equal to the number of grandchildren I could call my piece of code that would scroll to the wanted grandchild, but this feels like a lot of hassle.

I want to load the `GrandParent` before the data comes down from the server, to render a placeholder/loading element.
I am looking for a more elegant method to solve this.

UPDATE:
[Is componentDidMount of parent called after all componentDidMount of children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32814970/is-componentdidmount-of-parent-called-after-all-componentdidmount-of-children)

I know why my `GrandChild`ren's CDM is triggered after CDM of `GrandParent` just looking to have a different behaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end the most neat solution was the following:

I set up `ComponentDidMount` on `IntermediateParent` (works with `IntermediateParent2` as well) which calls an action creator that sets a flag `loadedX = true`.

Then, in `GrandParent`'s `ComponentWillReceiveProps` wait for the `loadedX` prop to become true. When this happens, manually call the desired 'callback' function. I inject the `loadedX` prop to `GrandParent` using `connect`.

Hope this also helps someone else. If you need more details ask in comments. I can also come up with some code for a more real world example.

Answer (score 1):

We know that the children will `render()` when the parent `render()`s. This means we need to hook onto a parent `render()` and see if the children exist yet. We don't want to hook onto a child `render()` because that will run too many times and is kind of out of the scope of the child.

Looking at the [React Component Lifecycle](https://www.wikitechy.com/tutorials/react/img/reactjs-images/ReactJS-components-life-cycle.png), we see that there are two ways to hook on after a parent `render()`, `componentDidMount()` and `componentDidUpdate()`. We know that we can't use `componentDidMount()` because the parent mounts before the children. However, we can use `componentDidUpdate()`. In your `componentDidUpdate()`, you can use `ref`s, `document.querySelector()`, `document.getElementById()`, etc. to get a reference to the child. Once you are able to get the child reference, set a boolean flag so you only run the callback inside `componentDidUpdate()` once.

I feel like this is a cleaner solution. I think the accepted answer is kind of roundabout. You modify the `IntermediateParent` with `ComponentDidMount()`, actions using a dispatched redux action or a callback function in parent, and then the `componentWillReceiveProps()`. The `componentWillReceiveProps()` will also require a boolean flag like my solution.

---

Actually, maybe it isn't out of the scope of the child. Another solution is for the parent to pass a callback down to the child to call during the child's `componentDidMount()`. This callback will be called each time a child mounts, but you can keep a boolean flag in the parent so that the code only runs once.