# React-Redux connected component doesn't get updated after state is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to use React-Redux. I have a situation where one connected component (**Coordinates.jsx**) nested in another connected component (**Canvas.jsx**).

Source code https://github.com/RinatRezyapov/Vault-13.git (yarn install and then yarn start)

In parent component **Canvas.jsx** I dispatch an action in **componentDidMount()** which immutably change state.

Canvas.jsx

`componentDidMount() {
     this.props.addCanvasSize(windowWidth, windowHeight)

}`

The problem is that after changing state the child component **Coordinates.jsx** doesn't get updated and console.log shows **undefined**.

Coordinates.jsx

`componentDidMount() {
console.log(this.props.canvasSize)
}`

I'm sure that state is updated correctly (checked with Redux devTool) and I guess I didn't mutate state in reduced.

If I wrap console.log(this.props.canvasSize) in setTimeout then it shows coorect state.

**index.js (store)**

```
const store = createStore(reducer,
window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__())

render(
<Provider store={store}>
<App />
</Provider>, 
document.getElementById('root'));
```

**actions/index.js**

```
export const addCanvasSizeAction = (windowWidth, windowHeight) => ({
type: 'ADD_CANVAS_SIZE',
windowWidth,
windowHeight
})
```

**reducers/reducer.js**

```
export const reducer = (state={}, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_CANVAS_SIZE':
    return Object.assign({}, state, {canvasSize: {canvasWidth: action.windowWidth, canvasHeight: action.windowHeight}})
    default: 
    return state
}
}
```

**components/App.jsx**

```
class App extends React.Component {
render() {
return (  
    <div>
            <CanvasCont />
    </div>
    )
}
}
```

**components/Canvas.jsx**

```
class Canvas extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);

}


componentDidMount() {
var windowWidth = window.innerWidth-100;
var windowHeight = window.innerHeight-100;
var createCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
createCanvas.id = 'canvas';
createCanvas.width = windowWidth;
createCanvas.height = windowHeight;
ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).appendChild(createCanvas);
var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
var ctx = createCanvas.getContext('2d');
 this.props.addCanvasSize(windowWidth, windowHeight)    
}



render() {
return (<div>
<CoordinatesCont />
</div>)
}
}
```

**components/Coordinates.jsx**

```
class Coordinates extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

}
componentDidMount() {
console.log(this.props.canvasSize)
}
render() {

    var inlineStyle={
        width: "800px",
        height: "600px"
    }
       return (
    <div >
<span  style={inlineStyle} onMouseMove={this.handleMouseMove}></span>
    </div>
)
}
}
```

**containers/CanvasCont.js**

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
state: state
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
addCanvasSize: (windowWidth, windowHeight) => 
{dispatch(addCanvasSizeAction(windowWidth, windowHeight))}
})

const CanvasCont = connect(
mapStateToProps,
mapDispatchToProps
)(Canvas)
```

**containers/CoordinatesCont.js**

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
canvasSize: state.canvasSize
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
})

const CoordinatesCont = connect(
mapStateToProps,
mapDispatchToProps
)(Coordinates)
```

Comment: Please put the code necessary to diagnose potential problems in the post itself rather than pointing to an external repository. How it's connected matters, state shape matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with parent/child relation, you should keep in mind that the `componentDidMount` is called on the children before it is called on the parent (as explained in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38472793/2745879)

So actually in your case, here is what happens:

1. the child triggers its `componentDidMount` callback but the state is not yet defined
2. your `console.log` is triggered but there is nothing in the `props`
3. the parent triggers its `componentDidMount` and update the state
4. if you call `console.log` in a timeout in the child, now your properties are up to date

Now if you want to solve this, you need to use the `componentWillReceiveProps` callback that will be called whenever new properties are given to the component. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops

Comment: Didn't know that child's componentDidMount is called first. Thank you for information, now I see what happens. It means that in this case the only way to update child component is to check nextProps and then force update of the component? Is there any other ways to keep components up to state? Maybe nest Canvas and Coordinates in App component (I mean get rid of parent/child relation?)

Comment: Oh no, I don't think you have to change anything. To be convinced that everything work as expected, try to add a `console.log(this.props)` in the `render` function of the child component, you will see (if I am correct) 2 logs the first one being `undefined` and the other one with the correct `canvasSize` value

Comment: @GalaxyWanderer It makes sense though, right? A component's children must mount before the parent component can be considered mounted.