# How can I make a wrapper component mount before its child components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a wrapper that does not mount the child if the user is not authenticated. Otherwise, it mounts and renders the child component.
Roughly looks like this:

```
export class RedirectOnCondition extends Component {
  render(){
     return this.props.isAuthenticated? this.props.children : null
  }
}
```

My issue is the the child still mounts before the parent has a chance to evaluate the condition. It's only after the child's componentWillMount` (and any associated API calls have fired and failed) that the parent's render kicks in and remove's the child. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32814970/is-componentdidmount-of-parent-called-after-all-componentdidmount-of-children) this is how React works.

How can I get around this?

Comment: how does the parent evaluate condition? you can keep initial value of the condition false and make it true if user is authenticated.

Comment: the condition is passed view redux connect, it is evaluating correctly, but as I said my issue is that the child mounts before the parent renders. I want to let the parent render first

Comment: We need more info on how are you actually using the RedirectOnCondition HOC and how this.props.isAuthenticated comes in

Answer (score 0):

In the first render, the parent component may have not yet received the props you need to process the conditional rendering of a children component. In this case, you may want to check first if the props is already there.

```
export class RedirectOnCondition extends Component {
 render(){
   return "isAuthenticated" in this.props ? this.props.isAuthenticated? this.props.children : null : null
 }
}
```