# React componentDidMount timing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

Is `componentDidMount` lifecycle method independent from sibling components? From example below it seems like it is invoked only after all sibling components have been mounted.

Let's say we have a top level component which renders 2 child components, first having simple `render()` and another having relatively slower `render()`.

Sample to reproduce: https://codesandbox.io/s/j43klml9py?expanddevtools=1

TL;DR:

---

```
class SlowComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // perf mark
  }

  render() {
    // Simulate slow render
    // Takes 50ms
    return <h3>Slow component</h3>;
  }
}

class FastComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // perf mark
  }

  render() {
    return <h3>Fast component</h3>;
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // perf mark start
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // perf mark
    // measure all marks and print
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <FastComponent />
        <SlowComponent />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

---

I expect `componentDidMount` timings to be like this:

1. `FastComponent` 10 ms
2. `SlowComponent` 50 ms
3. `App`  52 ms

But in reality what I get is both fast and slow component `componentDidMount` callbacks are fired at the same time, i.e.

1. `FastComponent` 50 ms
2. `SlowComponent` 51 ms
3. `App`  52 ms

Current sample and repro code uses mount callback but same applies to `componentDidUpdate`.

Full source:

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React, { Component } from "react";

class SlowComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    performance.mark("slow-mounted");
  }

  render() {
    // Simulate slow render
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
        const b = JSON.parse(
          JSON.stringify({
            test: "test" + i,
            test1: i * i * i
          })
        );
      }
    }
    return <h3>Slow component</h3>;
  }
}

class FastComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    performance.mark("fast-mounted");
  }

  render() {
    return <h3>Fast component</h3>;
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    performance.mark("init");
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    performance.mark("app-mounted");

    performance.measure("slow", "init", "slow-mounted");
    performance.measure("fast", "init", "fast-mounted");
    performance.measure("app", "init", "app-mounted");

    console.clear();

    console.log(
      "slow",
      Math.round(performance.getEntriesByName("slow")[0].duration)
    );
    console.log(
      "fast",
      Math.round(performance.getEntriesByName("fast")[0].duration)
    );
    console.log(
      "app",
      Math.round(performance.getEntriesByName("app")[0].duration)
    );

    performance.clearMarks();
    performance.clearMeasures();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Demo</h1>
        <FastComponent />
        <SlowComponent />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Quick answer: they are not independent.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32814970/is-componentdidmount-of-parent-called-after-all-componentdidmount-of-children

Comment: That one is talking about parent/child component dependency, my current question is regarding children components.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you are using the latest React version (16.5.0).

Assuming two components, one slow and one fast wrapped in a parent component the execution flow will be the following:

1. Parent component calls its `UNSAFE_componentWillMount` method
2. Iterates all children with the order they are defined in its render method and calls their `UNSAFE_componentWillMount` method
3. Iterate all children and call their `render` method(here your slow component expensive render method will kick-in)
4. Iterate all children and call their `componentDidMount` method
5. Parent component calls its `componentDidMount` method

This whole process is being done synchronously.

Going back to your example, this is why you see almost the same timing to both your components, because all component lifecycle methods are called as soon as the work is completed for all components.

In general, conceptually React consists of 2 phases, "render" phase and "commit" phase.
The "commit" phase is when React applies any changes, and in your example the lifecycle method `componentDidMount` is called in this phase.

You can follow this flow by debugging React, and viewing the stack trace which is the following:

```
componentDidMount
commitLifeCycles
commitAllLifeCycles
callCallback
invokeGuardedCallbackDev
invokeGuardedCallback
commitRoot
```

Answer (score 2):

As per your life cycle order, your componentDidMount will be called (as the name itself suggests) after your component has been mounted. Which will be after the DOM has been mounted, which in doing so will call your render.

Now assuming if there is no I/O i.e, async event happening in your child component anywhere.

(and even if there are any async event happening, the functions will be executed but the call stack will maintain the execution in the event loop.. but this is a separate discussion)

```
-- Parent
  -- Child-1
  -- Child-2
```

Order of execution

```
Parent constructor()
Child 1 constructor()
Child 1 render()
Child 1 componentDidMount()
Child 2 constructor()
Child 2 render()
Child 2 componentDidMount()
Parent componentDidMount()
```

As per the ReactJS docs the mounting triggers in order are

- constructor()
- static getDerivedStateFromProps()
- render()
- componentDidMount()

Reference of mounting order from react documentation [Mounting React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#mounting)

On a side note, another detailed read on the order of execution.
[Understanding React — Component life-cycle](https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-reactjs-component-life-cycle-823a640b3e8d)

Answer (score 1):

**The simple answer**

All components will fire `componentDidMount` method after all renders are completed. Because before to mount elements to DOM we need to create them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ComponentDidMount lifecycle method is independent from sibling components. It depends on how your render takes time because it invokes after your render complete. But the component mounts in same order as they are in parent component. E.g - In above example first fast component mounts then second component.

And you can't calculate how much time a function takes to iterate a loops. So here your assumption of calculating time of slow component's ComponentDidMount lifecycle method was wrong. You can't expect specific time estimate based on number of iteration without profiling.