# Passing props from state, into componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, properties, state

I have class which makes an api call, and sets the response data as the state value like so

```
    export class TestClass extends React.Component {
    state = {
       data: null 
    }

    componentDidMount(){
       fetch('http://www.nfl.com/feeds- 
       rs/bigPlayVideos/2018/REG/1.json')
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then(res => this.setState({ data: res.bigPlays }))
    }
```

The above code works and sets the state correctly. Then in the render i pass the properties like so.

```
     render (){
       const {data} = this.state;

       return ( 
        <div>
         <ChildComponent data={data} />
         </div>
        )
        }
```

My Child component looks like so

```
    componentDidMount(){
      const {data} = this.props
     }
```

The data prop comes in correctly in the render after the page updates but comes in as null in the componentDidMount. I need to do some further state updates, so is there anyway i can get access to the values in the componentDidMount(), if not where would be the best place to do further state logic in the ChildComponent class.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a normal behavior, since what actually happens is as follows: a `componentDidMount` of any parent component is not invoked unless all of it's childrens `componentDidMount` is invoked.

So, if component `B` is a child for component `A`, component `B` `componentDidMount` methods will be invoked before the one for `A` component since `B` is a child for `A`.

[Read more about this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32814970/is-componentdidmount-of-parent-called-after-all-componentdidmount-of-children)

So, if you want to solve this, you can use `componentWillRecieveProps` lifecycle instead.

```
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      if(typeof nextProps.data !== 'undefined'){
        this.setState({ data: nextProps.data });
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `componentDidUpdate` since `state.data` in the parent is initially null.

If you only want to deal with non-null `data` only mount the child once `data !== null`: `return <div>{data !== null && <ChildComponent data={data} />}</div>`

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use [`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) and check if `this.props.data` isn't null.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    const {data} = this.props
    if(data != null){
        // do what you want
    }
}
```

But you should also have one more condition to avoid that from happening on every render.

What you can also do is pass a default value to `data`.

```
const { data = [] } = this.props // default value is an array.
```