# how to link in a page with React Router v1.0.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-router

I want to link to a specific section section of a page with react router a lot like how anchor tags would work in html. However, I couldn't find solutions with React Router version 1.0.0.

Currently, i have my router like this:

```
let history = createHashHistory({
    queryKey: false
});

<Router history={history}>
        <Route path="/" component={a}/>
        <Route path="/b" component={b}/>
        <Route path="/c" component={c}/>
        <Route path="/d" component={d}/>
        <Route path="/e" component={e}/>
        <Route path="/f" component={f}/>
        <Route path="/g" component={g}/>
 </Router>
```

and I am trying to link to a specific section in the components like

```
 <Link to="/b#{div_id}"> Go to section with div_id is component {b} </Link>
```

Comment: See my update, this is not going to be supported

Comment: Is there any way to go to a certain part of a page with React then?

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30495062/how-can-i-scroll-a-div-to-be-visible-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 1):

<s>There is currently an open issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/394) for this. It doesn't appear to be supported, but it should be supported when using `HistoryLocation` when this issue is fixed.</s>

## EDIT

This is [no longer supported](https://github.com/rackt/history/blob/master/docs/HashHistoryCaveats.md#caveats-of-using-hash-history).

Comment: I saw that link and I thought they already fixed it. Thank you for confirming it is still not supported