# scrollIntoView is not a function JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, function, scroll

My script should scroll down to an element 2 seconds after the page is loaded. It should work only on mobiles.

```js
window.HTMLElement.prototype.scrollIntoView = function() {};

if (window.innerWidth < 500) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    let toogleElement = document.getElementsByClassName('eapps-google-maps-bar-toggle');
    toogleElement.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });
  }, 2000);
}
```

```css
#padding { height: 1000px; }
```

```html
<div id="padding"></div>
<div class="eapps-google-maps-bar-toggle" eapps-link="barToggle">Foo</div>
```

Comment: remove this ```window.HTMLElement.prototype.scrollIntoView = function() {};``` try again?

Comment: Your `scrollIntoView()` function doesn't do anything...? The issue itself is because `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection, not a single element. You need to either loop through all of them, or access one by index directly, eg. `toogleElement[0].scrollIntoView(...`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It removed error but script doesn't scroll to element (I have no console errors now)

Comment: Right, because you defined the function, but it contains no logic to actually perform the scroll operation.

Comment: I had this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53271193/typeerror-scrollintoview-is-not-a-function and solution of this question helped me so I made empty function. What should I write in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to remove `window.HTMLElement.prototype.scrollIntoView = function() {};` because you don't need to define your own funciton.

Second, `document.getElementsByClassName` return HTML collection and you can access the element your want by using `toogleElement[0]`.

**Example below**

```js
if (window.innerWidth < 2000) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    let toogleElement = document.getElementsByClassName('eapps-google-maps-bar-toggle');
    toogleElement[0].scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });
  }, 2000);
}
```

```css
#padding { height: 1000px; }
```

```html
<div id="padding"></div>
<div class="eapps-google-maps-bar-toggle" eapps-link="barToggle">Foo</div>
```