# How to test react component with refs?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-testing-library, ref

I have some react functional component:

```
export const Chat = props => {
  ..............
  const messagesRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => messages && messagesRef.current.scrollTo(0, 99999), [messages]);
  .............
  return (
    ...........
    <div className='chat-content__list' ref={messagesRef}>
    </div>
  ............
  )
}
```

I'm not good at testing and I just want to test the render of my component, the code is like this:

```
it('Render Messages chat', async () => {
   const { container } = render(<Chat ...someProps />)
}
```

After running this test, I get this error: ***TypeError: messagesRef.current.scrollTo is not a function***

How to work with refs during testing and how to fix the error in my case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: scrollIntoView is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53271193/typeerror-scrollintoview-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jest React tests run in an abstraction of the browser called [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom). Because it isn't a real browser not all functions are implemented. I suspect that the `scrollTo` is one such example.

For example, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53294906/8459521) suggests that `scrollIntoView` is also not implemented and to get around it you can provide a spy for it.

Jest supports having a setup file for setup code required by all tests. You can look into placing the mock there.