# TypeScript error: Property 'scrollIntoView' does not exist on type 'never'. TS2339

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In my component, I have the following code to scroll to the bottom of the page:

```
const el = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
    if (el.current === null) { }
    else
        el!.current!.scrollIntoView({ block: 'end', behavior: 'smooth' });

    if (props.loading != true)
        props.fetchFeedbackTaskPageData(submissionId);

}, [])
```

This `el` ref is attached to a div (at the bottom of the page) like this:

```
<div id={'el'} ref={el}></div>
```

However, I am receiving the following error:

> Property 'scrollIntoView' does not exist on type 'never'.  TS2339

When I was not using `!`, I was receiving this error:

> Object is possibly 'null'.  TS2531

I checked many posts on this issue but did not see how to handle this in react when using `useRef` and `scrollIntoView`. Any ideas?

Comment: how you are using ref?

Comment: @ravibagul91 `el` ref is attacthed to a div (at the bottom of the page): `<div id={'el'} ref={el}></div>`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You have to tell useRef what types other than null it will be assigned to, e.g. `useRef<null | number>(null)` or in your case `useRef<null | HTMLElement>(null)`.

The problem is that by assigning null as a default value to the ref, typescript can only guess that the type of the ref will be that of it's initial value (null) - which is why you're getting the errors you mentioned. Generally speaking, [refs don't have to be DOM components](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables), so useRef's type definition does not assume that it will be assigned to one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But, this is the problem I am facing. In all tutorials, `ref(null)` is used. I do no know how to define it otherwise.

Comment: Oh sorry - I think my comment was reformatted, let me fix that real quick

Comment: Instead of `number` I was supposed to put `HtmlElement`. Thanks again for the help on a vacation day.. :)

Comment: For anyone following this, it's `HTMLElement`.

Answer (score 107):

For anyone reading this in 2020 its

```
const el = useRef<null | HTMLDivElement>(null);
```

and no longer:

```
const el = useRef<null | HTMLElement>(null);
```

Comment: I'm wondering why we should ``useRef`` instead of directly ``document.findElementById()``

Comment: @daCoda It has to do with the Virtual DOM: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-internals.html

Comment: Great contribution. How could this be adapted for an array of html elements? eg.

```ts

const cardRefs = useRef([]);

  cardRefs.current = cardsPerPage.map(
    (card, i) => cardRefs.current[i] ?? createRef()
  );
```