# React Native Typescript : scroll with useRef and scrollIntoView

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, scroll

I wanted to be able to scroll to an element when I press on a element. (ex : I press D and it scroll down to the letter D) . Howether while there is no error here, it is not scrolling down.
Here is my code simplified:

```
const fieldRef = React.useRef<null | HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const scrollToElement = () => fieldRef.current?.scrollIntoView();
```

...

```
                    <Text
                      onPress={() => {
                        {
                          scrollToElement;
                        } }}
                     > 
                         Here
                     </Text>
```

...

```
<div ref={fieldRef}>
    <Text> Hello</Text>
</div>
```

I used these to try to correct my code:
[How to add "refs" dynamically with react hooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55995760/how-to-add-refs-dynamically-with-react-hooks)
as well as
[How to scroll to an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441856/how-to-scroll-to-an-element)
as well as
[TypeScript error: Property 'scrollIntoView' does not exist on type 'never'. TS2339](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57028500/typescript-error-property-scrollintoview-does-not-exist-on-type-never-ts23)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To scroll a certain amount down:

```
fieldRef.current!.scroll(0, fieldRef.current!.scrollTop +30)
```