# Adding a div to the bottom of a list view pushes all view upward out of viewport

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am implementing a chat view in `React`,and the desired behavior is that whenever new data is pushed into the `dataSource`, the chat view (an infinite list) scrolls to the bottom, there are many implementations, some found here: [How to scroll to bottom in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37620694/how-to-scroll-to-bottom-in-react).  However when I try to implement it, I am getting this strange behavior where all the views in the window are "pushed upward" out of sight by some 300px, as if to accomadate this new `<div>` that is at the bottom of the list view. My implementation below:

```
        import React, {useEffect, useRef} from "react";
        import { createStyles, makeStyles, Theme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
        import InfiniteScroll from 'react-infinite-scroll-component';


        const row_1 = 2.5;
        const row_chat = 4

        const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => createStyles({

            container: {
                width: '40vw',
                height: `calc(100vh - 240px)`,
                position: 'relative',
                padding: theme.spacing(3),  
            },

        }));


        const chat_container_style = {
            width: '40vw',
            height: `calc(100vh - 240px - ${row_chat}vh - ${row_1}vh)`,
        }




        function ChatView(props) {

            const classes = useStyles();
            const { _dataSource } = props;

            // scroll to bottom
            const messagesEndRef = useRef(null)
            const scrollToBottom = () => {
                messagesEndRef.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" })
            }
            useEffect(() => {
                scrollToBottom()
            }, [_dataSource]);


            return (
                <div className={classes.container}>


                    {/* chat window */}
                    <InfiniteScroll
                        dataLength={_dataSource.length}
                        next={() => { return }}
                        hasMore={true}
                        loader={<></>}
                        style={chat_container_style}
                    >
                        {_dataSource.map((item, index) => {
                            return (
                                 <div {...props} key={index} item={item}>
                                    {`item: ${index}`}
                                 </div>
                            )
                        })}

                        {/* putting an item here push all divs upward */}
                        <div ref={messagesEndRef} />
                    </InfiniteScroll>


                </div>
            )


        }
```

Note the use of `<InfiniteScroll/>` is not the cause of the behavior, Really if I put the `ref={messagesEndRef}` into any view, it pushes all the views up in the viewport.

Comment: I realized the answer is actually becuase of the `scrollIntoView` function, the issue is resolved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039885/scrollintoview-causing-the-whole-page-to-move

Comment: so this question is a duplicate ? Should we delete it, or can you answer it yourself ?

Comment: @kca I'll answer it. Neither of the sources I provided address this specific issue in its entirrety. and people upvoted it so i guess it's useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. The source of the issue is the `scrollIntoView` function, it's scrolling the entire page instead of just the `listView`, here's the correct `scrollIntoView` function with the correct parameters:

```
    const scrollDivRef = createRef();
    useEffect(() => {
        scrollDivRef.current?.scrollIntoView({
            block   : 'nearest',
            inline  : 'start',
            behavior: 'smooth',
        })
    }, [_dataSource.length]);
```

Here's how the ref is nested inside the DOM:

```
            <InfiniteScroll
                next={() => { return }}
                hasMore={true}
                loader={<></>}
                style={chat_container_style}
                dataLength={_dataSource.length}
            >   
                {_dataSource.map((item, index) => (
                    <BubbleView {...props} key={index} item={item}/>
                ))}
                <div style={refDivStyle} ref={scrollDivRef}/>
            </InfiniteScroll>
```

This problem has nothing to do w/ how I layout the style sheet.