# React .createClass() scroll to ref: scrollIntoView not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-router

I'm having trouble figuring out what's wrong when I'm trying to scroll to a "ref". I've been searching like mad and found urls which make complete sense, but it won't work in my scenario.

- https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/678
- http://codepen.io/takatama/pen/mVvbqx

I have an app using react 15.4.2 along with react-router 3.0.0. I have a route to a component that takes an optional route parameter and am trying to use that to scroll to the element on componentDidUpdate(). I've tried implementing a couple different ways but in following the most recent implementation of ref.scrollIntoView() I get an error...

> scrollIntoView is not a function

I made sure that the "ref callbacks" exist at the time of componentDidUpdate().

Am I just missing something like using .createClass() is missing methods you get when using a class definition or am I approaching this entirely wrong?

I could just jump to using a package, but things like this in not being able to understand what's going on when being as native as I can bother me.

> *Code has been simplified to showcase the issue while maintaining a similar flow. There may be discrepancies in code syntax.*

**APP**

```
const App = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <Router history={ appHistory }>
                <Route path='home' component={ Home }>
                    <IndexRoute component={ Page } />
                    <Route path='page(/:itemIndex)' component={ Page } />
                </Route>
                <Route path='add-new-item' component={ AddNewItem } />
            </Router>
        )
    }
});
```

**HOME**
is just a wrapper with a nav bar that renders children based on an active index

**ADD NEW ITEM**
is a component which will goto /page/[index of newly created item]

**PAGE**

```
const Page = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            data: undefined,
            scrollTo: parseInt(this.props.params.goalIndex) || undefined
        };
    },

    componentWillMount() {
        // this gets data and does a setState for data
    },

    componentDidUpdate() {
        let { scrollTo } = this.state;

        if( scrollTo && this['item-' + scrollTo] ) {
            this['item-' + scrollTo].scrollIntoView();
        }
    },

    renderTiles() {
        return this.state.data.map( ( item, index ) => {
            return (
                <Item
                    key={ 'item-' + index }
                    ref={ node => this['item-' + index] = node }
                >
                    <p>foo bar...</p>
                </Item>
            )
        });
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                { this.state.data && this.renderTiles() }
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A nested React component with a ref is just that and not a DOM element with DOM element methods so Element methods will not be available.

To easily fix, you can wrap the React component in a standard DOM element and assign a ref to that.

```
renderTiles() {
    return this.state.data.map( ( item, index ) => {
        return (
            <div
                key={ 'item-' + index }
                ref={ node => this['item-' + index] = node }
            >
                <Item>
                    <p>foo bar...</p>
                </Item>
            </div>
        )
    });
},
```

Comment: thanks so much. That is not obvious and I was bashing my head against the wall until I found this answer.

Comment: Thanks for that. It is very useful tip indeed!

Answer (score 0):

The concept from the accepted answer is specifically true for elements from UI frameworks such as Reactstrap, Semantic UI, Material UI, etc.

This is easily forgotten when they have the same names.

`<Input>` or `<Form>` in ReactStrap is not `<input>` or `<form>` !

Such a component with a ref is "not a DOM element with DOM element methods", as the accepted answer indicates.